# ggplot italicize part of legend across multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, typography

I am trying to *italicize* part of my legend elements. I have been able to get the subsets I want *italicized* using the answer in this [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186918/ggplot-italicize-part-of-caption-and-divide-text-over-two-lines), but this then creates problems with how the text shows up.

Here is the data (slightly modified):

```
Behaviour   Repeatability   Age stage
Activity    0.1             PE  A
Activity    0.5             PE2 A
Activity    0.5             PW  B
Activity    0.5             A   C
Activity    0.4             A2  C
Activity    0.4             PW1 B
Aggression  0.2             PE  A
Aggression  0.3             PE2 A
Aggression  0.3             PW  B
Aggression  0.4             A   C
Aggression  0.3             A2  C
Aggression  0.0             PW1 B
```

Here is the plot (without the *italics*):
[image]

When I try to *italicize* the legend text that are in brackets based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47186918/ggplot-italicize-part-of-caption-and-divide-text-over-two-lines), the plot gets messed up:

[image]

The code I use to get this plot is below (minus unneeded formatting):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = stage, y = Repeatability, shape = Behaviour, colour=Age, linetype=Age)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("#D55E00", "#0072B2", "black", "black", "#CC79A7", "black"), name = "Study", breaks=c("A","A2", "PE", "PE"=="PE2", "PW", "PE"=="PW1"),
    labels=c(
    (expression("Taylor et al. 2012", paste(italic("\n 366 adults")))),
    (expression("Boon et al. 2008", paste(italic("\n (71 adult females)")))), 
    (expression("This study", paste(italic("\n (102 juveniles)")))),
    "This study", 
    (expression("Kelley et al. 2015", paste(italic("\n (16 yearlings)")))), 
    "This study")) +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(2.5, 'lines'))
```

Comment: Multi-line expression are not well supported, also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223846/ggplot2-two-line-label-with-expression/32281523#32281523

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mentioned by [axeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4341440/axeman) in the commentary: Multi-line expressions are not well supported. If you use expression with `\n` you'll get adjustment problems. This happens, since the ggplot works with the grid maintainers (check [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1741) git issue).

You can linebreak in plot's with `atop`, which is a r base function and also works for ggplot. The following code is adjusted for your case. The expression is still needed for using `italic`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = stage, y = Repeatability, shape = Behaviour, colour=Age, linetype=Age)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#D55E00", "#0072B2", "black", "black", "#CC79A7", "black"), name = "Study", breaks=c("A","A2", "PE", "PE"=="PE2", "PW", "PE"=="PW1"),
                      labels=c(
                        (expression(atop("Taylor et al. 2012", italic("(366 adults)")))),
                        (expression(atop("Boon et al. 2008", italic("(71 adult females)")))), 
                        (expression(atop("This study", italic("(102 juveniles)")))),
                        "thisstudy",
                        (expression(atop("Kelley et al. 2015", italic("(16 yearlings)")))),
                        "thisstudy"))+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(2.5, 'lines'))
```

the output plot is as follows [image: output]

By default your labels get centered now, since `atop` creates a formula expression.

If you want to use your `expression` with `paste` you can do it like this:

```
(expression(paste("Taylor et al. 2012 \n", italic("(366 adults)"))))
```

but this occurs in wrong adjustment of the linebreak.

Comment: The `paste` in the expression is not necessary.

Comment: @January true, changed it

Comment: Thank you! That solution does the trick. Is there a way to have the labels left justified instead of centered?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist I don't know any way to change it, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change the alignment with this:

```
legend.text.align =
```

where 1 is **right** and 0 is **left**.

Comment: That helps slightly (for the first line, but not the second)